# How do I transfer ownership of a G Suite marketplace app?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace

Our organization has an app hosted on the G Suite Market place however this was created by an admin who is no longer with the organization.

How can you check who 'owns' the app and how can we transfer ownership of the app to an active admin?

Comment: Please post an answer once you learn the solution. I am interested in the answer and the process you went thru.

Comment: You must be a super administrator at least an admin role with data transfer privilege to do the [transfer of site ownership](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6399201?hl=en#). That's the reason why you need to assign [administrator roles](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172176?hl=en#) in some alternative user for this task to be done.